# sql query not working on node.js mysql but works on terminal

Tags: mysql, node.js

i have an sql query as follows

```
select profileName from user where (id) in ( select id FROM( SELECT user_id1 as id from user_connection where user_id2=(select id from user where profileName='deva') UNION ALL SELECT user_id2 as id from user_connection where user_id1=(select id from user where profileName='deva')) t GROUP BY id) ;
```

works like a magic on terminal, but on node.js it's having sql query error

```
exports.findFriends = function(userName,callback){
console.log('searching friends.... '+userName);
var findFriendsQuery = 'select profileName from user where (id) in ( select id FROM ( SELECT user_id1 as id from user_connection where user_id2=(select id from user where profileName= ? ) UNION ALL SELECT user_id2 as id from user_connection where user_id1=(select id from user where profileName=?)) t GROUP BY id)' ;
  db.query(findFriendsQuery,[userName],function(err,rows,fields){
    if(err){
     console.log(err);
     callback(1,-1,-1);
     }
    else{
        callback(0,rows,1);
        }
    });
};
```

> sqlMessage: 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near \'?)) t GROUP BY id)\' at line 1',
>     sqlState: '42000',
>     index: 0,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used the placeholder( `?` ) twice while passing only once, you need to pass twice( `[userName, userName]` )

```
exports.findFriends = function(userName,callback){
console.log('searching friends.... '+userName);
var findFriendsQuery = 'select profileName from user where (id) in ( select id FROM ( SELECT user_id1 as id from user_connection where user_id2=(select id from user where profileName= ? ) UNION ALL SELECT user_id2 as id from user_connection where user_id1=(select id from user where profileName=?)) t GROUP BY id)' ;
  db.query(findFriendsQuery,[userName, userName],function(err,rows,fields){
    if(err){
     console.log(err);
     callback(1,-1,-1);
     }
    else{
        callback(0,rows,1);
        }
    });
};
```